# Angular 2 - Two structural directives on the same DOM element

Tags: angularjs, angular

While playing around with Angular 2, I've encountered a problem: apparently I can't put two structural directives (`ngFor`, `ngIf`) on the same DOM element.
In Angular 1 this used to work. For [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CGMGoqZfP6EXan4BTZPB?p=preview):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$even">{{item}}</div>
```

When I try something similar with [Angular 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/A9vkVZhEUwimOWlw4WTh?p=preview):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="#item of items; #e = even" *ngIf="e">{{item}}</div>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.items = ["a","b","c"]
  }
}
```

Nothing happens. Not even an error.

If I put the `ngIf` directive on a child element, [it works](https://plnkr.co/edit/haueSjMEqeGZTGliB8qt?p=preview):

```
<div *ngFor="#item of items; #e = even"><div *ngIf="e">{{item}}</div></div>
```

But the problem is I don't want to add a child element just for that. If, for example, it's a `<tr>` tag inside a table, then adding a `div` inside will make the DOM weird.

I know Angular 2 is still in beta, but I'm wondering if it's a bug, a feature, or maybe there's an undocumented way to achieve what I want.

Comment: AFAIK this is just not supported. Using the explicit form `<template [ngFor]>` for one directive and the short form `*ngIf` for the other on the content of the template should work though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried the explicit `template` form, without success

Comment: Can you please add the code of this attempts as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, sure:  `<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items" #e="event" [ngIf]="e"><div>{{item}}</div></template>`

Comment: My suggestion was meant like to add only one of these directives onto `<template>` and the other to the content inside the template. Both on the same element are not supported AFAIK.

Comment: [tried that](https://plnkr.co/edit/3kGN6MEPZVcBVXZty37L?p=preview)...

Comment: event -> even: https://plnkr.co/edit/VCWOPCvpVKaBSei6QFnb?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two structural directives are not supported on one element. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4792

Instead nest them while using [template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template) for the outer one and micro syntax for the inner one.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not allowing this?

Comment: This syntax is a short form that expands to a canonical form. It's not clear how to expand to the canonical form if there are more than one. I guess it boils down to HTML not providing the order of attributes (directives), but the order is significant, like *ngIf outside *ngFor or the other way around, is not the same.