# Use *ngIf to filter tree nodes in clarity recursive tree

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have a recursive clarity tree

```
<clr-tree>
  <clr-tree-node 
      *clrRecursiveFor="let type of displayedTypes; getChildren: getTypeChildren" 
      [(clrSelected)]="type.selected"    
      [(clrExpanded)]="type.expanded"
    >
      {{type.name}}
    </clr-tree-node>
</clr-tree>
```

But I want to filter some tree nodes. In a simple case I would use `*ngIf` directive. But I already have another directive `*clrRecursiveFor` here. 
So I try to wrap it into `ng-container`.

```
<clr-tree>
    <ng-container  *clrRecursiveFor="let type of displayedTypes; getChildren: getTypeChildren" > 
      <clr-tree-node *ngIf="isVisible(type)"...>
          ...
        </clr-tree-node>
        </ng-container>
    </clr-tree>
```

You can see some examples [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bpqdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) in app.component.html

But in this case nothing is shown even if `isVisible` always returns true. How can I use *ngIf directive here to filter tree nodes?

Comment: seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100716/angular-2-two-structural-directives-on-the-same-dom-element

Comment: Elma, the solution from that question can't help me.

Comment: could you add stackblitz code ?

Comment: Elma, I'm not familiar with stackblitz. 
This is example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bpqdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

But it's now working properly

Comment: What is working properly ?

Comment: I mean, it is not working properly.

Comment: can you add the correct dependencies, css and make it work ?

Comment: Elma, yes, Now it works

Comment: So, is this question answered or is there more help that you need with your use case?

Comment: hippeelee, no. It's not answered yet

Comment: I think this is an internal bug of this lib, they trying to get the context even if it’s not existing... you can maybe filter your array insteed and show always all the elements of it

Comment: Ok, Elma. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible now. It's better to filter array in a component.